# In a NAS box, why would a volume be have Status Degraded, when the volume was only ever made up of 1 disk

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, raid, nas, freenas

I am running a FreeNas box with 5 HDDs in and each HDD has its own Volume associated with it.

It has always been this way, none of the volumes have ever been made from multiple disks.  Also the disks themselves are all marked as 'Healthy'

Why are all my volumes being marked as 'status = DEGRADED'?

Is it just because the volume is only made up of one disk and it is expecting it to be made up of multiple?

Its also worth saying I am running on FreeNas 9.1.1 (old I know but no reason to update) And the volumes were made under the UFS volume manage (legacy ).

Below are screen shots of the Disks, the volumes and then the status of one of the volumes

[image: List of Disks]

[image: List of volumes (there are 2 more than disks because 2 disks have failed, but they still have corresponding volumes.)]

[image: Status of 1 of the volumes]

Please ignore the disks that are marked as unknown status (they have failed)

Comment: What kind of volumes are they?

Comment: @Seth How would I find out?  What are the different types? (sorry my knowledge of volumes is pretty poor)

Comment: Are you sure the 5 volumes aren't accidentally spread over the 5 disks? How did you find out that the status is "_Degraded_"?

Comment: @Attie Pretty sure as when I look at the volume status in FreeNas GUI, under each volume, it only lists 1 disk  (and the status of the disk is online while the status of the volume is 'degraded')

Comment: [FreeNAS volume management documentation](https://www.ixsystems.com/documentation/freenas/9.3/freenas_storage.html#volumes) and [documentation on viewing](https://www.ixsystems.com/documentation/freenas/9.3/freenas_storage.html#view-volumes). For example a "raidz" entry would indicate that you'd be running not just a single disk. Maybe take a screenshot of that screen and attach it to your question.

Comment: @Seth I have added screenshots.  When I set it up ages ago I didn't want any shared disks.  I wanted basically for this NAS to be JBOD as I didn't want the extra complications.  If this is not the case and they are actually shared how would I undo it...

Comment: @Seth these volumes were made with the UFS volume Manager, (not ZFS) and for each volume, only 1 disk was used to create it.

Comment: As you've hidden the names of the volumes what does their structure actually look like? 5 disks and 7 volumes would indicate that at least one disk has several volumes on it?

Comment: @Seth 2 of the disks have failed and have been removed from the box, but their corresponding volumes still exist in the volume list.  so that is why there are 2 more volumes than disks.  the list of disks and volumes are flat lists with no structure.